# Sum only Values of columns in array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have a bidimentional array, And I wanna sum the values of the second value of row.

Example, my array is

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

I want this output, the value I want to sum to the second value of row is 5

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

I try this but sum the two values:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {    
        bolax[i][j]=bolax[i][j]+suma;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code.  This is not enough to be helpful.

Comment: `bolax[i][j]=bolax[i][j]+j;`

Comment: The example output does not make sense. Isn't the sum of each column 15?  Even the sum of the rows would be something else (2, 4, 6, 8, 10).

Comment: @user3528438 Yes, this work, but I wanna sum other value, not the J index

Comment: @e0k I want to sum a X value only for the second value of row

Comment: then add an `if` in the loop, but that smells unless you make it clear what you really want to do, like what if the input has three columns and what you want to do with the third column,

Comment: I think you mean "add" rather than "sum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds `suma` to the second value of each row:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    bolax[i][1] += suma;
}
```

Since the array index starts with 0, the second value is index 1.